# WCF service looks works for one client solution, but not another

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF service that I have written, and exposed as a windows service. In Visual Studio 2010 for two apps, I can right click on references, select "Add Service Reference...", put the required information in, and it works just fine.

For a different application, when I do this everything looks to be working fine, but when I look at the service in the object browser, all I am seeing is one class and an enumeration. The service class, along with several classes and enumerations are missing. All projects are 3.5.

What would cause something like this? Oh, and if I click the advanced tab in the "Add Service Reference..." dialog box and connect to the service as web service, it works.

I don't want to connect to it as a web service for multiple reasons however (one being the enumerators values are explicit, and this is lost over a web service.)

Thanks in advance,
Jeremy.

Answer (score 2):

Insufficient information but it looks like in the first case your Service and Client projects might be sharing some C# types.

When using SOAP those types would be recreated but in another WCF project they are just skipped.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Not sure what you said was the problem, but it did lead me to what the problem is.

In the project that the service does not work right it, I actually have the business logic of the service included as a reference DLL (I am in the process of re-writing the app to use the service and not the DLL).

Thanks to your comment, I just for fun removed the DLL reference and added the service reference, and it worked. If I add the DLL reference back in, and add or update the service, the classes go away.

Not sure why this is happening, as the namespaces are different.

Thanks!